# How to improve the performance of Fortran intrinsic function calls when function argument is a variable

Tags: performance, variables, arguments, fortran

I am writing a Fortran program which involves a very large number of exponential function calls. I found that when the argument of `exp()` function is a variable, the calculation speed is more than 20 times slower than using constant value as the function argument. Eg, in the following two sample programs, program A is much slower than program B.

```
program A
real a,b
integer i

a=1.234
do i=1,100000000
  b=exp(a)
end do
stop
end program A
```

=====================

```
program B
integer i
real b

do i=1,100000000
  b=exp(1.234)
end do
stop
end program B
```

When using variable as the `exp()` function argument is unavoidable, how can I improve the efficiency of doing `exp()` calculations?

Comment: When you ask a question like "why this code is 20 times faster than that code" you should _also_ include the name of the compiler used, compile options (_at least_ provide the level of optimisation) and possibly the hardware that executes it. We are not psychics here.

Comment: I tested the Fortran codes on a laptop (can't remember the CPU/memory etc) with Compaq Visual Fortran under default compile option settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some compilers can evaluate intrinsic functions applied to constants at compile time.  Thus there is no run time cost to evaluating the intrinsic function in this case.  Obviously this can't be done for true variables since the values won't be known until runtime.

Comment: And some compilers can spot a loop whose contents don't change (as in OP's `program B`) and go through it only once.

Answer (score -1):

See if you can get some optimisation report out of the compiler...

Example for Intel:

```
program A
real a,b
integer i

a=1.234
!DIR$ SIMD
do i=1,100000000
  b=exp(a)
end do

stop
end program A
```

Example using OpenMP:

```
program A2
USE OMP_LIB
real a,b
integer i

a=1.234
!DIR$ SIMD
do i=1,100000000
  b=exp(a)
end do

stop
end program A2
```

And of course in this trivial case...

```
program B2
real a,c
real, DIMENSION(100000000) ::b

a=1.234
c=exp(a)
b=c
!  which is mathematically the same as
!b(1:100000000) = c
!  or
!b(:) = c

stop
end program B2
```

I usually put these types of functions into a library and then compile that using !DIR@ or !$OMP and get it tuned up, independent of the main program's optimisation level.

```
MODULE MyFuncs
PRIVATE
PUBLIC, B2

CONTAINS
PURE SUBROUTINE B2(a,n,b)
IMPLICIT NONE
real              , INTENT(IN   ) :: a
INTEGER           , INTENT(IN   ) :: n
real, DIMENSION(n), INTENT(  OUT) :: b

c=exp(a)
!DIR$ SIMD
b=c

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE myB2

END MODULE MyFuncs

program A
IMPLICIT NONE
USE myFuncs
INTEGER            :: n=100000000
real               :: a
real, DIMENSION(n) :: b

a=1.234
CALL MyB2(a, n, b)

end program A
```